# How to get the last row of Excel file using Oracle Forms

Tags: excel, oracle, plsql, oracleforms

I'm importing data from Excel to database table using Oracle Forms. Here is the code I'm using:

```
ligne_fin := 300;

FOR Z in 2..ligne_fin LOOP
  ligne:=Z;

  v_societe := Excel.get(1,Z,1)  ;
  v_compte := Excel.get(1,Z,2);
  v_Tiers := Excel.get(1,Z,3);
  v_section := Excel.get(1,Z,4);

  insert into EntrCl (SOCIETE, 
                      COMPTE, 
                      TIERS, 
                      SECTION)                      
    VALUES (v_societe,
            v_compte,
            v_Tiers,
            v_section);             
END LOOP
```

With my get function

```
function GET(FOLIO in NUMBER, prow in number,pcol in number) 
  RETURN varchar2 
is
  deger varchar2(800);
Begin
  deger:='';

  args := OLE2.create_arglist;
  OLE2.add_arg (args, FOLIO);
  Worksheet:=OLE2.GET_OBJ_PROPERTY(workbook,'Worksheets',args);

  args:=OLE2.CREATE_ARGLIST;
  OLE2.ADD_ARG(args, prow);
  OLE2.ADD_ARG(args, pcol);
  cell:=ole2.get_obj_property(worksheet, 'Cells', args);

  deger := OLE2.Get_Char_Property(cell, 'Text');
  OLE2.RELEASE_OBJ(cell);
  OLE2.destroy_arglist (args);

  return(deger);
end;
```

My issue is that I want to get my ligne_fin automatically using code. I don't want to hardcode it.

Is there any way to get the last record of Excel file using PL/SQL ?

Comment: Kind of a work around, but what if you stored the last_row range using excel formula/vba in a separate cell somewhere and then simply acquiredthe data (using get method)  for your sql?

Comment: I think this is very bad idea to use Forms OLE2 to do what you do. The OLE2 is slow and there are other, probably easier ways to do this. SQL Loader, External tables, insert/Append, UTL_FILE to name a few, and using Oracle SQL Developer is probably the easiest way. Is there a reason using forms?

Comment: Yes the client want to upload the data via a form and not from sql developer or any other tool. I totaly agree it's too slow. Is there any other solution but using forms of course ? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if a column returned null value to identify last row

```
 Z:=2;
 While(Excel.get(1,Z,1) is not null)
 loop 
 v_societe := Excel.get(1,Z,1)  ;
 v_compte := Excel.get(1,Z,2);
 v_Tiers := Excel.get(1,Z,3);
 v_section := Excel.get(1,Z,4);

 insert into EntrCl (SOCIETE, 
                  COMPTE, 
                  TIERS, 
                  SECTION)                      
VALUES (v_societe,
        v_compte,
        v_Tiers,
        v_section);  
 Z:=Z+1;
 end loop;
```